# open raster in R! and some statistical operation

Tags: r, gis, aggregate, raster

I would like to open raster files (in ASCII or TIFF format), aggregate their cells and after this operation count correlation between values in this new raster file and another one. Unfortunately I do not know what is wrong in my commands - I get an error message:

```
x <- GDAL.open('~/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI 113_121/TVDI_kamp_evi_TRANSF.asc')
```

> CPL ERROR 4: `~/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI 113_121/TVDI_kamp_evi_TRANSF.asc' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
>
> Error in .local(.Object, ...) : `~/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI 113_121/TVDI_kamp_evi_TRANSF.asc' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Comment: Start with the basics, re-assigning "r" from an installed (system) file with your own local path to a file is maybe ok, but unreadable, unformatted, and completely unclear code is not. Please, put some thought in to what you are asking and, take some time on this one, think about what someone might have to do to empathize with your problem.

Comment: There are two questions here, IMO: 1) how do I read GISy raster data into a respectable R object, 2) how do I aggregate sensibly from respectable R objects.   I don't think 2) is really worthwhile as a part of this question, since there are many other resources for it. 1) is arguably harder to learn about.

Comment: Maybe try `fn <- file.choose(); x <- GDAL.open(fn)` to make sure you get a file that is really there. Also consider renaming appropriately to avoid spaces in the file path, which might be screwing things up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are having trouble getting the filenames, you might do this:

```
my_asc_files = dir("../somepath", pattern="*.asc", recursive=T, full.names=T)
files_I_want = my_asc_files[c(1,12,32,33)]
```

Then you can load your files like this

```
library(raster)
my_rasters = lapply(files_I_want, raster)
```

Then you may do this:

```
pairs(my_rasters)
```

and this:

```
for(i in 1:length(my_rasters)) 
  for(j in i:length(my_rasters))   
    if(i != j) {
      df = na.omit(data.frame(values(my_rasters[[i]]), values(my_rasters[[j]])))
      cor(df[,1], df[,2])
    }
```

Although you will run into problems if the rasters are so large that you cannot hold two in memory at the same time. Without a better question it will be hard to give you better advice.

Comment: or simply: s <- stack(files_I_want); pairs(s)

Answer (score 5):

To read (open) a raster, one way is to use `readGDAL`:

```
library(rgdal)
r <- readGDAL("~/myhome/thisdir/IhaveaFile.asc")
```

This is my personal preference, and the only reason to otherwise use `GDAL.open` or `raster` is if my machine doesn't have the RAM (+abit) to deal with the data set in question.

Comment: r <- readGDAL('home/mateuszk/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI 113_121/TVDI_kamp_evi_TRANSF.asc')
CPL ERROR 4: `home/mateuszk/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI 113_121/TVDI_kamp_evi_TRANSF.asc' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  `home/mateuszk/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI 113_121/TVDI_kamp_evi_TRANSF.asc' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Comment: I do not know why I get tnis error... Maybe this kind of operations is much easier under GRASS GIS (as I know, there is no such function as aggregate in simplier QGIS)

Comment: All of your problems stem from a basic inability to locate or read the file.  Have you tried the various suggestions here for locating the file?  Have you tried eliminating the space in the path name?

Comment: Space is needed (folder names contain it)

Comment: OK - I can open an raster file (using rgdal), but unfortunately I can not use it for aggregate function:Error in getS3method(gen, cl, TRUE) : 
  no slot of name "methods" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"                                                          How should I convert it (I open it using GDAL.open)

Comment: Instead of GDAL.open I Use readGDAL, but I still have problems...                What is "by argument"?                                                       r <- aggregate(x,fun='mean')
Error in aggregate.Spatial(x, fun = "mean") : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default